# Query nested JSON in MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb

so I have the following nested collection in a MongoDB database:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('615e9b8d17fa084f2e8d4b83'),
 'status': 'Played',
 'roundId': 4165363,
 'gameweek': 2,
 'teamsData': {'12274': {'scoreET': 0,
                         'coachId': 89543,
                         'side': 'home',
                         'teamId': 12274,
                         'score': 0,
                         'scoreP': 0,
                         'hasFormation': 1,
                         'formation': {'bench': [{'playerId': 101652,
                                       'assists': '0',
                                       'goals': 'null',
                                       'ownGoals': '0',
                                       'redCards': '0',
                                       'yellowCards': '0'},
                                        ....
                                        {'playerId': 90991,
                                       'assists': '0',
                                       'goals': 'null',
                                       'ownGoals': '0',
                                       'redCards': '0',
                                       'yellowCards': '0'},
            '9598': {'scoreET': 0,
                     'coachId': 122788,
                     'side': 'away',
                     'teamId': 9598,
                     'score': 3,
                     'scoreP': 0,
                     'hasFormation': 1,
                     'formation': {'bench': [{'playerId': 69964,
                                   'assists': '0',
                                   'goals': 'null',
                                   'ownGoals': '0',
                                   'redCards': '0',
                                   'yellowCards': '0'},
                                    ....
                                    'lineup': [{'playerId': 69616,
                                    'assists': '0',
                                    'goals': '1',
                                    'ownGoals': '0',
                                    'redCards': '0',
                                    'yellowCards': '39'}
```

I want a list of **playerId** and **goals** and I know I can project something like

```
list(db.matches.find({},
                     projection = ['teamsData.9598.formation.lineup.playerId', 'teamsData.9598.formation.lineup.goals']))
```

which would bring me

```
[{'_id': ObjectId('615e9b8d17fa084f2e8d4b83'),
  'teamsData': {'9598': {'formation': {'lineup': [{'playerId': 69616, 'goals': '1'},
      {'playerId': 14812, 'goals': 'null'},
      {'playerId': 69409, 'goals': 'null'},
      {'playerId': 25393, 'goals': 'null'},
      {'playerId': 135747, 'goals': 'null'},
      {'playerId': 3476, 'goals': '1'},
      {'playerId': 105361, 'goals': 'null'},
      {'playerId': 8287, 'goals': '1'},
      {'playerId': 69396, 'goals': 'null'},
      {'playerId': 69968, 'goals': 'null'},
      {'playerId': 14943, 'goals': '0'}]}}}}]
```

The problem is that I don't want to write down **9598** part in the project code (and then for each teamId), otherwise I won't be able to scale it through whole collection. Is there anyone know how can I take playerId and goals for all teams?

I read several questions regarding nested JSON but none in a structure like that, so I appreciate any help. Thanks :)

Comment: you are using data on keys, and that makes queries hard, think about replacing `teamsData` with an array, and make the key part of the embeded document. Unknown keys make data querying/updating hard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- for all documents and for all teams keys
- gives a list of playerId and goals, for every team
- converts to array the object
- `$map` on members, keep only team-key and only the playerId and goals

*i dont know what you really want, but maybe this can help.
*if you want for a specific team-key, you can filter the array with `$filter`

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eMs44tAP9sA)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$project": 
    {"teamsData": 
      {"$map": 
        {"input": {"$objectToArray": "$teamsData"},
          "in": 
          {"$mergeObjects": 
            [{"teamId": "$$this.k"},
              {"players-goals": 
                {"$map": 
                  {"input": "$$this.v.formation.lineup",
                    "in": {"playerId": "$$t.playerId", "goals": "$$t.goals"},
                    "as": "t"}}}]}}}}}])
```

Comment: Thanks @Takis _. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: ok good, think about using arrays for data, because unknown keys are hard in MongoDB.
saving data on your schema(as field names for example) is making the queries harder in general.

Comment: Thanks again. I will study more about ```$map``` and ```$objectToArray```. This is a JSON file made publicly available from Russia 2018 World Cup and I though it would be more interesting to practice in a real dataset, with real issues instead of those perfectly examples we found in the documentations.

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience, I do not recommend using dynamic value as key for MongoDB documents as it would be hard to maintain and difficult to compose queries.

Nevertheless, you may do the followings in an aggregation pipeline:

1. `$objectToArray` in `$addFields` to convert the `teamsData` into an array of k-v tuples
2. Here I take a guess that you just want team 9598's line up data. So I did a `$unwind` followed by a `$match` to filter out the data.
3. `$project` the `teamsData` back into an array of k-v tuples, which k is the team ID and v is the `playerId` and `goals` tuples in `formation.lineup`
4. `$arrayToObject` to convert the `teamsData` back into your desired form of output

Here is the [Mongo playgronud](https://mongoplayground.net/p/F0gFUCe5E8O) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks @ray. I will study more about it to undestand the steps you suggested. This is a public dataset from the 64 matches of 2018 World Cup, so I want a query that works for both teams on 64 matches. I though It would be challenging to practice with a real dataset, that comes with real issues we face right? Really appreciate your help :)